# font in safari not working , showing unsupported character

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

font in safari not working , showing unsupported character but working fine in chrome and firefox.

[image]

But same site looking bad in safari

[image]

Comment: Aw, come on. You should know the routine by now. Just two screenshots and nothing else will not magically produce a solution.

Comment: It doesn't look like a font issue, by the way, more like an encoding issue.

Comment: Sorry sir, i m an iphone developer and for that doesn't know very well in html. Can u please guide how can i fix it.

Comment: Create a [mcve], or if you can't make that work, at least provide a link to the website where this happens.

Comment: @MrLister - https://www.premiernssa.com is the website, please check on safari